# wsgi autoreload for django on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: django, apache2, wsgi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, django-wsgi

I am trying to get WSGI to auto-reload after any changes to the code in my django project.

Everything is set up and the website runs without errors however for some reason when I modify a python code file (e.g. views.py) the website simply doesn't update.

I followed this article:
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html

Which entails creating a **monitor.py** containing:

```
# Apache WSGI monitor script for django
#---------------------------------------
# monitors django app and reloads apache2 if any python files are changed
# written for Python 3
# to use - import into wsgi.py

import os 
import sys 
import time 
import signal 
import threading 
import atexit 
import queue

_interval = 1.0 
_times = {} 
_files = []

_running = False 
_queue = queue.Queue() 
_lock = threading.Lock()

def _restart(path): 
    _queue.put(True) 
    prefix = 'monitor (pid=%d):' % os.getpid() 
    print('%s Change detected to \'%s\'.' % (prefix, path), file=sys.stderr)
    print('%s Triggering process restart.' % prefix, file=sys.stderr)
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

def _modified(path): 
    try: 
        # If path doesn't denote a file and were previously 
        # tracking it, then it has been removed or the file type 
        # has changed so force a restart. If not previously 
        # tracking the file then we can ignore it as probably 
        # pseudo reference such as when file extracted from a 
        # collection of modules contained in a zip file.

        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            return path in _times

        # Check for when file last modified.

        mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
        if path not in _times:
            _times[path] = mtime

        # Force restart when modification time has changed, even
        # if time now older, as that could indicate older file
        # has been restored.

        if mtime != _times[path]:
            return True
    except:
    # If any exception occured, likely that file has been
    # been removed just before stat(), so force a restart.

        return True

    return False

def _monitor(): 
    while 1: 
        # Check modification times on all files in sys.modules.

        for module in sys.modules.values():
            if not hasattr(module, '__file__'):
                continue
            path = getattr(module, '__file__')
            if not path:
                continue
            if os.path.splitext(path)[1] in ['.pyc', '.pyo', '.pyd']:
                path = path[:-1]
            if _modified(path):
                return _restart(path)

# Check modification times on files which have
# specifically been registered for monitoring.

    for path in _files:
        if _modified(path):
            return _restart(path)

    # Go to sleep for specified interval.

    try:
        return _queue.get(timeout=_interval)
    except:
        pass

_thread = threading.Thread(target=_monitor) 
_thread.setDaemon(True)

def _exiting(): 
    try: 
        _queue.put(True) 
    except:
        pass 
        _thread.join()

atexit.register(_exiting)

def track(path): 
    if not path in _files: 
        _files.append(path)

def start(interval=1.0): 
    global _interval 
    if interval < _interval: 
        _interval = interval

    global _running
    _lock.acquire()

    if not _running:
        prefix = 'monitor (pid=%d):' % os.getpid()
        print('%s Starting change monitor.' % prefix, file=sys.stderr)
        _running = True
        _thread.start()
    _lock.release()
```

And then importing this into **wsgi.py**:

```
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sandbox.settings')
    
    import sandbox.monitor
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    
    sandbox.monitor.start(interval=1.0)
    sandbox.monitor.track('/root/webdev/projects/sandbox/catalog/views.py')
    
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Note: I'm using views.py for making changes to test autoreload, however making changes to other files doesn't work either.

My environment (for local web development):

- Python 3 with django in virtualenv
- Apache2
- Windows Subsystem for Linux (Debian 10)
- vscode IDE

I've tried debugging using a django launch config in vscode and monitor.py has an error occurs the line:

for module in sys.modulesvalues():

```
def _monitor(): 
    while 1: 
        # Check modification times on all files in sys.modules.

        for module in sys.modules.values():

Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
dictionary changed size during iteration
  File "/root/webdev/projects/sandbox/sandbox/monitor.py", line 66, in _monitor
    for module in sys.modules.values():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 885, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
```

This error occurs on the 2nd 'read through' of monitor.py.

However I have no idea if this is the source of the problem or something due to the debug setup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For me its reloading without any hassle.
My **wsgi.py**

```
from django.core.wsgi 
import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blog.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Are you running Apache2 or the built in django runserver?  I'm running the website on Apache2 locally (via mod_wsgi) rather than on the django runserver.

Comment: django runserver